# How to get rid of magick_alloc_size macro redefined warnings

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I'm using Magick++ in a C++ program, and I see the following warning message:

```
In file included from /Users/jwoods/Projects/glidar/src/main.cpp:40:
In file included from /Users/jwoods/Projects/glidar/src/scene.h:37:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++/Include.h:42:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h:71:
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/method-attribute.h:120:11: warning: 'magick_alloc_size' macro redefined
#  define magick_alloc_size(x)  __attribute__((__alloc_size__(x)))
          ^
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/method-attribute.h:132:11: note: previous definition is here
#  define magick_alloc_size(x)  /* nothing */
          ^
In file included from /Users/jwoods/Projects/glidar/src/main.cpp:40:
In file included from /Users/jwoods/Projects/glidar/src/scene.h:37:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++.h:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++/Include.h:42:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h:71:
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/method-attribute.h:121:11: warning: 'magick_alloc_sizes' macro redefined
#  define magick_alloc_sizes(x,y)  __attribute__((__alloc_size__(x,y)))
          ^
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/method-attribute.h:133:11: note: previous definition is here
#  define magick_alloc_sizes(x,y)  /* nothing */

2 warnings generated.
```

I'm including Magick++ in what I think is the normal way from my header file,

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
# define MY_HEADER_H
# include <Magick++.h>
#endif
```

so I assume the problem is in Magick++, not my program.

I searched the Google a bit for this warning, but haven't found any obvious solutions for getting rid of it.

Comment: can you give compilation command line or makefile? I think you maybe missed Magic++-config.

Comment: It looks like you have an incorrect method-attribute.h header file in wand. It should be wand_alloc_sizes in that file.

Comment: @SHR I'm using CMake, but I'll have a look at trying to find a different FindMagick++ this week.